# Django enable URL link in template

Tags: django

I have a blog and users can comment any articles. For now, when they post an URL, we can not follow the link by a clic. Because there is no  tag.

I know we can display HTML by using the filter "|safe". But I don't want a user using all html tag for security reasons.

I just want to make URL like "http://google.fr" as active and cliquable.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`urlize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) filter does exactly what you want.

Comment: I didn't know this filter ! Thank you.